# Excel VBA naming and changing source of Power Query

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

I have a sheet with 2 queries in it that query 2 different web pages that I am using as a template. I need to create many more sheets with the same 2 queries with different sources and names(to make it easier to index).

However I cant figure out how to change parameters on queries. I have everything else done so far.

I used the record macro to get me started by recording me manually copying the template page and changing the values however the macro couldn't even set the values properly. it used following query

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("queryname").Name = "newname"
```

This doesnt work at all.I have also looked around and found people that had success with.

```
.Listobjects("queryname").QueryTables.Name = "newname"

QueryTables.("queryname").Name = "newname"
```

This is the macro I have so far. all it does is copy the current text from selected cell and use that to name everything after copying the template sheet.

Excel doesn't throw any errors running this code. It runs the entire code but doesn't change the name of the tables.

```
Sub Setup()
    Dim item As String
    Dim bName As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim TbName As String
    Dim TsName As String

    item = Selection.Value

    Sheets("Query Template").Copy Before:=Sheets(6)
    Sheets("Query Template (2)").Select
    Sheets("Query Template (2)").Name = item

    sName = "S_" & Replace(item, " ", "_")
    bName = "B_" & Replace(item, " ", "_")
    TbName = "BTemplate (2)"
    TsName = "STemplate (2)"

    'this is where I try to change the query names.
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - " & TbName)
        .Name = "Query - " & bName
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - " & TsName)
        .Name = "Query - " & sName
    End With

    Sheets(item).Range("A2:D2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="BLink" & Replace(item, " ", "_"), 
        RefersToR1C1:="='" & item & "'!R2C1"

    Sheets(item).Range("F2:I2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SLink" & Replace(item, " ", "_"), 
        RefersToR1C1:="='" & item & "'!R2C6"

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. All I need is the ability to change source and name of the query.

Comment: I may be wrong, but you might need to access the `Name` member of the `WorkbookQuery` object, which is a member of the `Queries` collection which is a member of the `Workbook` object. The `WorkbookQuery` object also has other members that might be relevant e.g. `Formula`. This may all depend on what Excel version you have.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Ya the WorkbookQuery object was what I needed to use. But now I am having the issue that after everything is copied and named the query doesn't refresh. just keeps saying there are no connections to this query and I need to delete the table then re load the query to the sheet. I started a script to load query to sheet but it says there is no query with that name even though the properties of the sheet says the exact same name.

Comment: I don't have access to a PC right now and I haven't worked with Power Query automation enough to write something from memory, but I found this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1. There is potentially ready-to-use code there that matches what you want to achieve. Maybe have a look at the names of the subs to understand what they do and if they're of any use to you.

Comment: Thanks Chillin that helped alot. Using some of the code from that link I managed to just copy the M code from template queries to create new queries and place them on the sheets. I got it to work however now that I have alot of queries made the sheet is taking up alot of memory so I may have to split each pair of queries into its own workbook.

Answer (score 0):

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1

Thanks To Chillin for finding this link.

Using some of the code from that link I managed to just copy the M code from template queries to create new queries and place them on the sheets. I got it to work however now that I have alot of queries made the sheet is taking up alot of memory(10G RAM) so I may have to split each pair of queries into its own workbook and update/save each one in order.